# Automatize web actions without need to open the browser

Tags: javascript, html, web, web-applications, server

I have to execute code of a web page (action of uploading files, a button for a popup, ..) without the need to open the browser, automate it in a code (JavaScript for example). Do you know if its possible and how?

Thank you

Comment: you can google around with the term "headless browser".

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to use [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/)... You can use it in many languages including Node.JS (https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver).

I think program still needs to open web-browser or atleast start it in background but seems this is what you are looking for.